# QueryBuilder in java

Tags: java, jquery, query-builder

I am looking for inbuilt querybuilder plugin in java which allow user to create custom queries.Something like [this](http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/asp-net-mvc/).But this is built for .net and php.But i am using java and html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

typical implementation if ORM is hibernate or eclipseLink, .... . For creating type safety query you can use mysema see [enter link description here](http://www.querydsl.com/)